# Como atribuir NA como valor?

Tags: r

Tenho a seguinte linha de código:

```
enem$TP_COR_RACA <- factor(enem$TP_COR_RACA, levels = 0:5, 
  labels = c("Nao", "Branca", "Preta", "Parda", "Amarela", "Indígena"))
```

Quero substituir as ocorrências do valor `"Nao"` por `NA`, ou seja, campo vazio.

Answer (score 6):

Como você está utilizando fatores, você pode também pode mudar diretamente os `levels`:

```
levels(enem$TP_COR_RACA)[levels(enem$TP_COR_RACA) == "Nao"] <- NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Rode

```
enem$TP_COR_RACA[enem$TP_COR_RACA=="Nao"] <- NA
```

O código `enem$TP_COR_RACA=="Nao"` vai encontrar as linhas da coluna `enem$TP_COR_RACA` que são iguais a `"Nao"`. Depois, basta substituir as observações presentes nestas posições por `NA`.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o `ifelse` também:

```
enem$TP_COR_RACA <- ifelse(enem$TP_COR_RACA == "Nao", NA, enem$TP_COR_RACA)
```

O `ifelse` recebe três argumentos:

1. Uma comparação: `enem$TP_COR_RACA == "Nao"`
2. Resultado se a comparação for verdadeira: NA
3. Resultado se for falsa: enem$TP_COR_RACA (o próprio valor do vetor)

Ele fará a comparação para cada elemento do vetor.

---

Outra forma é a função `recode_factor` do `dplyr`.

Exemplo:

```
> a <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "Não", "a"))
> recode_factor(a, `Não` = NA_character_)
[1] a    b    c    <NA> a   
Levels: a b c
```